# Definition of functional derivative

Tags: definition

In [this book](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=nIk6AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=quantum%20field%20theory%20blundell&hl=ko&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q=quantum%20field%20theory%20blundell&f=false),
A derivative of a function is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{df}{dx} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon) - f(x)}{\epsilon}.
\end{equation}

And define a functional derivative of a functional $F[f]$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\delta f}{\delta f(x)} =
  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F[f(x^\prime) + \epsilon\delta(x-x^\prime)] - F[f(x^\prime)]}{\epsilon}.
\end{equation}

I don't understand why change of functional F is $\epsilon\delta(x-x^\prime)$. Why not define
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\delta f}{\delta f(x)} =
  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F[f(x^\prime) + \epsilon] - F[f(x^\prime)]}{\epsilon}~?
\end{equation}
What is the meaning of $\epsilon\delta(x-x^\prime)$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The correct mathematical dedefinition of "functional" derivative is given by either the Fréchet or Gâteaux derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion :

$\begin{equation}
  \frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)} =
  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F[f(x^\prime) + \epsilon] - F[f(x^\prime)]}{\epsilon}
\end{equation}$

would be the normal derivative of $F()$ at the point $f(x')$. The point of a functional derivative is that $\delta(x-x^\prime)$ is an unknown function that goes to zero at the boundaries. In contrast $\epsilon$ is just a number.
So we are determining an extremum of $F(f(x))$ by allowing small changes in $f(x)$ , not in $x$.

Some extra info that may help understand : 
$F()$ is not a 'normal' function ('normal' being for example : $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ ). Instead of a number, $F()$ maps a function  (e.g. $f(x)$ ) to a number. A trivial example would be : $F(f(x))=\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$.

A functional derivative normally gives you as output not a function, but a differential equation with which you can determine $f(x)$. 
So you're determining for which function $f(x)$ , $F(f())$ will be an extremum.